# Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)\sin y}{y \ln x }$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to compute $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)\sin y}{y \ln x }$$

I dont know how to do it; I just evaluated $x$ and $y$ limits separately and got $1$. I'm not sure about this, though.

Answer (score 2):

If both $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ converge to a and b respectively, then $f(x)g(y)$ converges to $a*b$

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin In what way does this not answer the question?  
This user gave exactly the right info to solve the problem, and its much better for OP to take this answer and apply rather than rotely jot down the right answer...

Comment: after split up , how do i evaluate $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)} \frac{siny}{y}$$

Comment: Use l'hopital rule